# Is Dirac's delta function well-defined at Lebesgue points?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Usually in textbooks, 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{y})$$
holds given $f$ is continuous. On the other hand, the definition of Lebesugue point $\mathbf{y}$ is that the following limit exists
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{|B_{\epsilon}|}\int_{B_{\epsilon}}f(\mathbf{x}),
$$
where $B_{\epsilon}$ is the ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered around $\mathbf{y}.$
Lebesgure differentiation theorem says for $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ function almost every point is a Lebesgue point.

All these facts let me think the delta function is also well-defined almost everywhere for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ because the definition of Lebesgure point is exactly an example of approximation of the delta function. More precisely, can the definition of the delta functional be extended to the domain $L^1$ in this way?

For delta function, we take this definition: The delta function is a generalized function that can be defined as the limit of a class of delta sequences. My question is to extend this functional to $L^1$ such that the extended delta function is a linear bounded functional on $L^1.$

Comment: A salient property of Delta function being that it is not a function, you might want to make precise the definition you are using. For some choices, the property you ask about is part of the definition (and not only when $f$ is continuous).

Comment: @Did Yes, I am exactly asking whether the definition of delta functional can be extended to the domain $L^1.$ It seems true to me.

Comment: WHICH definition? That is the whole point...

Comment: @Did Good question. Let us take this one: The delta function is a generalized function that can be defined as the limit of a class of delta sequences. Let us extend its definition to $L^1$ by requiring it is a linear bounded functional.

Comment: Please include this (or rather, a more *precise* definition than the one in your comment) in the question, to make it complete.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that one can easily extend the definition so that, for each $f\in L^1$, for almost all $a$, $\int\delta(x-a)f(x)\,dx$ is defined; just define it to be the limit in the Lebesgue density theorem. But you seem to want the quantifiers in the other order: For almost all $a$, for all $f\in L^1$, $\dots$. I see no reasonable way to get this.  That is, "almost all" refers to an exception set of measure zero, and I see no way to make that set independent of $f$.

Answer (score 5):

(Too long for a comment)

In my opinion, this is an interesting curiosity and I think the correct answer is what Andreas has said - simply define $\langle \delta_a,f\rangle$ as the Lebesgue limit.  This might save you some space if you need to say something like "the value of $f$ at $x$" in the context of an $L^1$ function (for which function values are not usually uniquely defined, as pointed out by T.A.E.). However I can't see this being of much use beyond that context, at least as far as distribution theory goes. The whole point of the theory of distributions is to work with as *nice* of a test function space as possible so that you can deal with 'nastier' distributions.  In this sense $L^1$ (or any space defined in terms of integrability properties) makes a very poor test function space because it's too 'big'.  Indeed most of the time it works precisely the other way around - $L^1_{loc}$ serves as our space of 'regular' distributions, i.e. we test *with* $L^1$ functions, not *on* $L^1$ functions.

Answer (score 2):

An element of $L^{1}$ is an equivalence class of functions which are equal a.e.. Elements of $L^{1}$ don't have pointwise values. Point values can make sense for specific cases, such as when there is a function in the equivalence class which happens to be continuous--that's because if there is such a function in the equivalence class, then there cannot be a different continuous function in the same equivalence class. However, point values are not determined in general.

Comment: Isn't the point of Lebesgue points sort of that at these points point values do make sense?  I hadn't thought about it that way until now.